# What are all ways of charging batteries?

Tags: space-engineers

Recently, Keen Software House added Battery blocks to the game that can power your ship and small stations.

What are all the possible ways to charge a battery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that in order to charge a battery you need a power source (duh!). You can charge a battery with solar panels, nuclear reactors or another ship/station.

You need to have your working power source on the same grid as your battery or have your ship docked to a grid with a power source. You can dock using a merge block or any other blocks that allows you to transfer ressources.

You could have a station with multiple reactors/solar panels and multiple docking ports. This would allow you to have your own recharge relay so you can charge your small ships there.

As you already know, a battery is used to store power, any kind of power. If you can generate power, you can store that power in a battery as long as the power can get to a battery. They get power the same way other blocks get power. Must be on the same grid and turned on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also charge a battery with another battery, if you explicitly set one to charge.

Actually useful if you have small battery powered vehicles and want to recharge them faster than your other power sources would be capable of.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the above answers: You can charge batteries by consuming iron/silicon/nickel.  When batteries are built, they have 25% charge (some sources claim it varies by battery type, which makes the standard-size, small-grid battery the most material efficient process for this).  You can therefore extract useful energy from newly constructed batteries, and then destroy them.  Doing so sacrifices the energy cells, however, resulting in a total loss of the necessary nickel and silicon, and most of the iron (you get some metal scraps back as a rebate).  The other components grind cleanly, however.

To do this, build a new battery on the grid you'd like to charge the existing battery on, set the new battery to 'discharge' OR the existing battery to "recharge."  The former method is safer, but not all of the energy in the new battery will go to charging the old one, some of it will go to the grid.

Once the new battery's lights turn red, indicating it is out of charge, grind it off. Rinse and repeat as needed, or as you have the materials to do so.

This process is even more efficient if you're using looted power cells (such as from wolves).  If you're stuck somewhere with stone, but no ice, wind, uranium, or sunlight, this can get you out of a tight spot.